# android, libgdx fixed navbar ontop of dynamic pane

Tags: android, android-layout, libgdx

I'm new to android/libgdx and I'm trying to create an android game that has a map editor.  I would like there to be a fixed nav bar at the top of the screen that is above a pane where I can view and interact with the map.  I would like to be able to zoom in and scroll around the map without effecting the nav bar.  What is the best way to do this?

Example:

```
|-----------------------------|
|   buttons here              |
-------------------------------
|        map editor pane      |
|                             |
|                             |
-------------------------------
```

Thanks,

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scene2d UI](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui) would be a good starting point. It provides a very flexible means of creating GUIs in libgdx.

The entire screen could be a [Table](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#Table), with one row containing the [buttons](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#Button), and another (taller) row containing a [ScrollPane](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#ScrollPane) for the map editor.